# Custom class using TokenFilterFactory in SOLR 4.3.0

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to upgrade my custom class to support SOLR 4.3.0 (from SOLR 3.5.0) hence I am trying to update my test classes to test the changes.

I got to know that we need to call the TokenFilterFactory constructor with key value pair map in SOLR 4.3.0 as below,

```
public class CustomFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory {
protected CustomFilterFactory(Map<String, String> args) {
        super(args);
    }
...
}
```

I am confused about the value that needs to be passed as key value pair. For ex:

If I have a field name as location and a custom class named com.solr.analysis.CustomFilterFactory, what should I pass as a key and value?

```
 <fieldtype name="Location" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" stored="false" multiValued="true">
      <filter class="com.solr.analysis.CustomFilterFactory" />
</fieldtype>
```

Can I do something like below in case if I am not planning to pass any other parameter to this  class?

```
args.put(new HashMap());
CustomFilterFactory(args);
```

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Where did you pass it if you declared CustomFilterFactory in your schema?

Comment: I passed the values from my SOLR test program. In general the values wil be passed from schema.xml (<filter class parameters>).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just passed empty map to CustomFilterFactory method and everything worked perfectly fine.

```
  Map<String,String> args = new HashMap<String, String>();
  CustomFilterFactory factory = new CustomFilterFactory(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but a workaround. You could choose to configure a custom analyzer instead. I looked at RemoveDuplicateTokenFilter source and example configuration tried to replicate for MyCustomFilter and MyCustomFilterFactory but it didn't work. Specifically, SolrResourceLoader kept complaining about a missing init(Map<String,String>) method for my custom token filter (strangely silent for RemoveDuplicateTokenFilter). So I opted to build an Analyzer and stick that in instead. Example code would go something like this:

```
class MyCustomAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

  @Override TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldname, Reader reader) { 
    Tokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_43, reader)
    TokenFilter filter = new MyCustomTokenFilter(source)
    new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter)
  }
}
```

and then configure it like so:

```
<fieldType name="text_mc" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index" class="com...MyCustomAnalyzer"/>>
  ....
</fieldType>
```